# Method that counts amount of chars

Tags: java

I've created a bank. I need this `"Luhn"` class to validate the social security number. The problem is, when the user inputs a number that's 1-9 digits, the program just stops. I want it to show a message like `"Invalid input. Please try again".` How do i do that?

```
package bank6;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Luhn {    
    public static boolean checkLogin(String custPnr) {
        int length = custPnr.length();
        int sum = 0;
        int pos = length-1;
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++, pos--){   
            char tmp = custPnr.charAt(pos);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tmp));
            int produkt;
            if (i % 2 != 0){
                produkt = num * 1;
            }else {
                produkt = num * 2;
            }
            if ( produkt > 9 )
                produkt -= 9;
            sum += produkt;
        }    
        boolean korrekt = (sum % 10) == 0;
        if (korrekt){
            System.out.println("Correct");
            return true;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            return false;
        }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pnr;      
        System.out.println("Welcome customer. Please login by using your "+ "birthdate (yymmddxxxx)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        pnr = input.nextLine();
        checkLogin(pnr);
    }
}
```

EDIT;

Okay, i edited my code. But i still get errors. I Think im kind of retarded when i comes to coding. Im about to eat my own head soon.
I understand why i am getting infinite recurse but not how to fix it. And how do i fix so i dont have to print out the message to the customer two times?

i am trying to build a bank. To even get logged in to watch your accounts and so on you need to validate you're a Swedish citizen by typing in a Swedish social security number. This is a class were the validation of code is. The codes mission is to validate the security number. If the number is fake, the code will give an "false" return (bottom of code) and "true" return if its true. The problem i had in the start was that if someone typed in a 1-9 digit number then it would just crash. I wanted it to give a "Sorry, invalid input. Please try again" and then the user was supposed to be taken back to the login and try again.

I couldn't run the code from the main class so i had to make a main at the bottom of the page just to be able to fix the above problem.

That's were im at now.

```
package bank6;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Luhn {

public static boolean checkLogin(String custPnr) {

    String pnr;

    System.out.println("Welcome customer. Please login by using your "
            + "birthdate (yymmddxxxx)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    pnr = input.nextLine();

    do {
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Try again.");
        checkLogin(pnr);
    } while (pnr.length() != 10);

    int length = custPnr.length();

    int sum = 0;
    int pos = length - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++, pos--) {

        char tmp = custPnr.charAt(pos);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tmp));

        int produkt;
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            produkt = num * 1;
        } else {
            produkt = num * 2;
        }
        if (produkt > 9) {
            produkt -= 9;
        }
        sum += produkt;
    }

    boolean korrekt = (sum % 10) == 0;

    if (korrekt) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pnr;

    System.out.println("Welcome customer. Please login by using your "
            + "birthdate (yymmddxxxx)");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    pnr = input.nextLine();
    checkLogin(pnr);
}
}
```

Comment: what is the condition for invalid ?

Comment: Have you looked at `String.length()`? Note that your loop should probably run from 0-9, not 1-10.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the use input, just use an if-statement to check the length.

Example

```
String str = input.nextLine();
if(str.length() > 9){
    // Print error message
}else{
    checkLogin(str);
}
```

You could use a do-while loop and use `str.length() > 9` as the condition so that it loops until a valid string of characters is entered. If you haven't used `do-while` loops, try googling them!

Comment: I have tried this Before i asked the question. But then i get error sayin "missing return statement" at the last brace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++, pos--)
```

You always loop from 1 to 10 as if there were 10 characters. If the user inputs a String smaller than 10 characters, your "pos" will go beyond 0, and you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` here:

```
char tmp = custPnr.charAt(pos);
```

Instead you should try:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=length; i++, pos--)
```

To check the length of the input before you perform the check:

```
String str = input.nextLine();
if(str.length() != 10){
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again");
    return false;
}else{
    checkLogin(str);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need that because if a person type "1985" as their year of birth (which isn't that unusual in Sweden) the code will only use the 10 last digits anyway. With that change you suggested the user will get "invalid" instead.

Comment: @Ribban Then check the length of the input string before doing the check, like other people suggested. Added solution for your issue with "return".